MAUI XAML Label with Different Font size
I need a label to show a number in the range of thousands. I'm not using thousand separator as per requested, but I want the user to be able to focus on the thousands. For example if I were to show "14013", I want the "14" to be shown in a bigger font size than "013".
I'm using a workaround of turning the number into string and using two separate label, but is there any string format I can actually use to make this into just one label?

Updates
You could use Binding value converters together with Span.
I made a demo for the case.
Here is MyConverter class. For example, if you pass a string like 12345, the converter will return 12 or 345 according to the Parameter passed to it.
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public MyConverter()
    {
    }

    public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        if((string)parameter == "thousand")
        {
            return str.Substring(0,str.Length - 3);
        }

        return str.Substring(str.Length - 3);
    }

    public object? ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}

Then consume it in XAML,
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="myconverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

......

<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="{Binding MyText,Converter={StaticResource Key=myconverter},ConverterParameter=thousand}"
                  TextColor="Red" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="20"/>
            <Span Text="{Binding MyText,Converter={StaticResource Key=myconverter}}"

                  FontSize="14"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>

In this way, you don't have to separate into two strings in the ViewModel.

Here is the screenshot

Hope it helps!

I am using MVVM Binding. So in the end I still do have to separate the value into two strings. Thank you for the answer.

@DeanThomas if you don't want to separate the value, I recommend you using Binding value converters. Please check my updates.
